# Is it possible to selectively define a type in a derived class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template which looks like this:

```
template <Base>
struct foo : Base
{
  typedef int some_type;
};
```

and I have a base which looks like this:

```
struct some_base
{
  typedef float some_type;
};
```

Now `foo<some_base>::some_type` will be `int` as the derived `foo` will hide the `Base::some_type`. What I would like to do, is that if `Base::some_type` is defined, use that else, define `some_type` locally in `foo` as  '`int` - so question is, is this possible?

I could invert the relationship and save myself some headache, however it's not very logical in the real application...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything is possible with a bit of template metaprogramming :)

Start by writing a metafunction that determines whether a type has a nested type called "some_type". Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_some_type
{
    typedef char no;                    // type with sizeof == 1
    typedef struct { char x[2]; } yes;  // type with sizeof == 2

    template <typename X, typename Y = typename X::some_type>
    struct foo {};

    template <typename X>
    static yes test(foo<X>*);

    template <typename X>
    static no test(...);

    static const bool value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes));
};
```

Now you can do something like this in the derived class:

```
template <typename T, bool has_some_type>
struct get_some_type;

template <typename T>
struct get_some_type<T, true>
{
    typedef typename T::some_type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct get_some_type<T, false>
{
    typedef int type;  // the default type
};

template <typename base>
class derived : base
{
    typedef typename get_some_type<base, has_some_type<base>::value>::type some_type;

    ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
struct sfinae_types
{
  struct yes { char x; };
  struct no  { char x[2]; };
};

template<class T>
class has_some_type : sfinae_types
{
  private:
    template<class U>
    static yes test(typename U::some_type *);
    template<class U>
    static no test(...);
  public:
    enum { value = (sizeof(yes) == sizeof(test<T>(0))) };
};

template<bool, class T, typename DT>
struct get_some_type
{
  typedef DT type;
};

template<class T, typename DT>
struct get_some_type<true, T, DT>
{
  typedef typename T::some_type type;
};

struct B1
{
};

struct B2
{
  typedef float some_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct D : T
{
  typedef typename get_some_type<has_some_type<T>::value, T, int>::type some_type;
};

#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

int main()
{
  std::cout << has_some_type<B1>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(D<B1>::some_type).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << has_some_type<B2>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(D<B2>::some_type).name() << std::endl;
  return(0);
}
```

And is a slight variation of what HighCommander4 presented a few seconds above...

I guess boost::mpl may come handy here and provide some useful TMP expressions I hand crafted above.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer, I've accepted HighCommander4's answer, as you said I think that answer was first(?)

Answer (score 1):

Give `struct foo` an additional template argument that defaults to `int`:

```
template <Base, Typedef = int>
struct foo : Base
{
  typedef Typedef some_type;
};
```

Then `foo<some_base, some_base::some_type>::some_type` is `some_base::some_type`.

Comment: this will work as long as the base type defines `some_type`, if it doesn't you'll get a compiler error... try this: `struct someother_base {};`, there is no `some_type` defined there, so the above will fail..

Comment: If `some_base::some_type` is not defined, then leave out the second TEmplate argument. `foo<some_base>::some_type` will be `int`. My solution was not meant to be completely automatic, but it's the only one I can think of.